# mysql: alter large table, disk space issue

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to alter an over 100Gb MySQL table.
According to manual MySQL is first creating an altered copy of the table, then replace it with the new one.

But, MySQL tries to create the copy in /tmp but the filesystem there is much smaller.
In result, mysql fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 3 (HY000) at line 1: Error writing file '/tmp/STa3x0Vi' (Errcode: 28)
```

How can I make mysql go a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link posted by Marc, you should do this:

```
export $TMPDIR=/some/other/path/with/enough/space
```

Now, alter your table...

Answer (score 0):

`df -h` check the size of your `/tmp` parition (if it's a partition) and make sure you have enough free space to create the backup there. If not, change your temp directory.